# pythonでsqlite3を使う際に変数に置き換える方法

Tags: python, sqlite

pythonを用いてsqlite3へとデータベース保管しようとしているのですが、sqlite3のデータの追加の文で日付の入ったものを保管しようとしましたが、シンタックスエラーでうまくできません。
どのようにすれば改善できるのか教えていただきたいです。

カラムはid(integer型)とdate(text型)です。
よろしくお願い致します。

コードは現在このような感じになっています。

```
import sqlite3
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import os
import datetime
import shutil

x,y = np.loadtxt('exp-data.txt',delimiter=' ',unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y)

os.chdir("/home/デスクトップ/uploader/public/uploads/user/avatar/1") #change directly

plt.savefig('sample.png')

time = datetime.datetime.now()
newname = "{0:%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S}.png".format(time)
os.rename("sample.png", newname)

newtitle = "{0:%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S}".format(time)

os.chdir("/home/ienaga/デスクトップ/uploader/db") #change directly
connector = sqlite3.connect("development.sqlite3")

sql = "insert into graph('1', newtitle) values"
sql += "'"+str(newtitle)+"');"

connector.execute(sql)

connector.commit()
connector.close()
```

エラー内容を記入します

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yomikomi01.py", line 28, in <module>
    connector.execute(sql)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "'2016-04-13-14:29:45'": syntax error
```

Comment: シンタックスエラーも質問に追記すると回答が付き易いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。シンタックスエラー内容ものせておきます。

Answer (score 2):

「カラムはid(integer型)とdate(text型)です」と言うことなら、sqlの前半もおかしいんでは無いですかね。

```
sql = "INSERT INTO graph(id,date) VALUES('1',?)"
connector.execute(sql, [newtitle])  # 追記部分をご覧ください
```

値を埋め込む時は直接SQL文を文字列として作らず`?`で埋め込んだ方が良いと思います。

---

(追記)
上記のコードも一応手元の環境で動くことは確かめたものですが、コメントに書いていただいたように、ドキュメントでは`?`に対する値はtuple of valuesで指定すると書かれていて、コード例も一貫してそれに合わせてあるので、2行目は次のように書いた方が良いと思われます。

```
connector.execute(sql, (newtitle,))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく動作し、カラムに登録もされていました。
構文等よくわかっていなかったため、とても参考になりました。本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: `execute`に渡すデータは`tuple`じゃないとダメだったような気がしましたが、違いましたっけ？

Comment: とりあえず私自身は「tupleでないとダメ」と言う記述は見つけられなかったのですが、「たまたま動いている」型のコードになっている可能性もあるので、もし何か典拠になる記述を見つけられたら(or 既にご存知でしたら)お教えください。

Comment: [ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)のプレースホルダの項目で「tuple of values」とありますね。おそらく、上記のデータは厳密には`[(newtitle,)]`と書かないといけない…？

Comment: 見つかりました。リンク先の上の方ですね。`[(newtitle,)]`だとarray of tuplesと書かれるはずなので、「tuple of values」なら`(newtitle,)`が正解ですね。`executemany`には(tupleの)arrayだけでなく、iteratorなんかも使えると明記してあるのに、placeholderに関してはそんな記述が見つかりませんから、tupleにしておいた方が安全そうです。回答の方、修正しておきます。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記のように変更させておきます。

Comment: あ、リストにしているのは複数件を一度に実行する場合の記述方法です。一件だけならタプルのみで良いはずです。複数件の場合は「タプルのリスト」を引数に渡す必要があります。

Comment: すみません上記の「タプルのリスト」は`executemany`の話ですね…

Answer (score 0):

以下でどうでしょう？

```
connector.execute("insert into graph (newtitle) values (%s)", (newtitle,))
```

Comment: 確認してみましたがエラーが出てしまいました。
以下のようなエラー内容です。
%は使えるのでしょうか？？
 connector.execute("insert into graph (newtitle) values (%s)", (newtitle))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: [マニュアル](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)では`?`か`:名前`ですね。

Comment: ？の方でやってみたところ出来ました。
ありがとうございました！

Comment: あっ、すみませんでした。 %s じゃなくて ? ですね。 @KenjiNoguchi  フォローありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

以下が間違っています。

```
sql += "'"+str(newtitle)+"');"
```

正しくは

```
sql += "('"+str(newtitle)+"');"
```

SQLのシンタックスエラーは作ったSQL文をログに出力する、もしくはコンソールに出力すると確認しやすいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すみません、初歩的なミスでした。
ただ、このあとも続いてエラーが出たのですが、これは、私のsqlite3でのカラムの指定が間違っているのでしょうか？